# Runtime.getRuntime Telnet could not opened

Tags: java, process, connection, telnet, runtime.exec

```
      package burak;

        import java.io.*;

public class Server {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        String[] command = new String[2];
        command[0] = "cmd";
        command[1] = "telnet";

        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line = reader.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
            line = reader.readLine();
        }
        BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
        String Error;

        while ((Error = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(Error);
        }
        while ((Error = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(Error);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
 }
}
```

I want to open telnet and send some commands but ı failed to open telnet what is wrong can you tell me?and ı need some examples about telnet conneciton expcect apache.common because ı have to use many ips in one run and ı dont know how to use args in this condi

Comment: Read (and implement) *all* the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).  That might solve the problem.  If not, it should provide more information as to the reason it failed.  Then ignore that it refers to `exec` and build the `Process` using a `ProcessBuilder`.  Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for arguments which themselves contain spaces.